# How to edit custom spelling dictionaries?

Tags: auto-correct, dictionary

Is it possible to extract the custom user spelling dictionaries from a rooted Android 4.0 phone? The built-in dictionary really sucks for languages other than English and I'd like to complement it with a few thousand more words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[User Dictionary Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usr.dict.mgr) might be what you are looking for.

From the description:

> UDM is an application that allows you to
>   edit/export/import/delete/clean the user dictionary words found on
>   your Android phone.

[image]